# Pandas DataFrame- Iterate and compare with before values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Unique_ID':  [44,66,12,76,57,83],
        'Location 1': ['AA', 'BB','CC','DD','EE','FF'],
        'Location 2': ['FF', 'CC','AA','EE','BB','CC'],
        'Rank':[1,2,3,4,5,6]
    }
pd.DataFrame (data)
```

Here is the sample dataset which should look like as shown below

[image]

**Expected Output:**

[image]

It is sorted based on the rank.
I am looking for a final dataframe(df2) with a best 'location 1' and 'location2' combination based on the rank.
Example:

- **Iteration-1:** As this is the best so there is nothing to compare with so we straight away insert first record in the new dataframe
  (df2).
- **Iteration-2:** Compare Location1 and Location2 if any of this exists in new dataframe(d2) of lcoation1 and location2 then do not insert else insert In this example we need to insert rank 2 records as "BB" and "CC" doesnt exists before.
- ****Iteration-3:***** Check if "CC" or "AA" exists in new data frame(d2). If **either one or both** presents do not update it into new dataframe. In this case both of them exits hence do not update this record into new dataframe.
- **Iteration-4:** Check if DD or EE is present in new dataframe. We dont see both of them in new dataframe hence update this record into new dataframe

And iterating it through each record .........

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use:**

```
m1 = df[['Location 1', 'Location 2']].stack().duplicated()
m2 = ~m1.any(level=0)
df = df[m2]
```

**Details:**

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to reshape the dataframe with columns `Location 1` and `Location 2` to `Multilevel` series and use [`Series.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) to create a mask `m1`.

```
print(m1)
0  Location 1    False
   Location 2    False
1  Location 1    False
   Location 2    False
2  Location 1     True
   Location 2     True
3  Location 1    False
   Location 2    False
4  Location 1     True
   Location 2     True
5  Location 1     True
   Location 2     True
dtype: bool
```

Use [`Series.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html) on `level=0` on the mask `m1` and negate this to create a new boolean mask `m2`. Thanks to @ScottBoston for suggestion.

```
print(m2)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

Finally using this mask `m2` filter the rows in the dataframe:

```
print(df)
   Unique_ID Location 1 Location 2  Rank
0         44         AA         FF     1
1         66         BB         CC     2
3         76         DD         EE     4
```

Comment: My answer was to similiar to yours.  +1

Comment: Thanks Scott, that's a nice suggestion :), will keep in mind.

Comment: Thanks @ShubhamSharma this has been a great help. somehow this logic isnt working in below scenario. 

import pandas as pd

data = {'Unique_ID':  [44,66,12,76,57,83],
        'Location 1': ['AA', 'BB','GG','DD','EE','HH'],
        'Location 2': ['FF', 'CC','AA','EE','HH','GG'],
        'Rank':[1,2,3,4,5,6]
    }
df=pd.DataFrame (data)
df

Comment: I should be seeing "HH" and "GG" as location 1 and location 2 as fourth record in final dataframe. Since this combination isn't existing so it need to inserted into the final dataframe

Comment: @Harish `HH` from  `HH GG` already appear before in the combination `EE HH`??

Comment: It should be compared with the new dataframe not with the old one though. In the new dataframe you wouldn't find "HH" and "GG". Below was my explanation before.

Iteration-2: Compare Location1 and Location2 if any of this exists in new dataframe(d2) of lcoation1 and location2 then do not insert else insert In this example we need to insert rank 2 records as "BB" and "CC" doesnt exists before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218373/discussion-between-shubham-sharma-and-harish).

Comment: @Harish Can you please join the chat room?